# XSLT Template doesn't match correctly XML source

Tags: xml, xslt

My Problem ist that my stylesheet isn't maching my xml file correctly. If comment out the template for `Machine`-tag, i see my table of Errors, if i have the stylesheet like I posted it here, I only see the generated link of my Machine-tag, but none of the errors.

I have the following XML Source file:

**XML:**

```
<Machine HtmlUri="http://stackoverflow.com" Name="XY1">
  <Errors Count="2">
    <Error>
      <TimeStamp>2013-11-12T07:27:24.9766747+01:00</TimeStamp>
      <Machine>XY1</Machine>
      <Message> ... </Message>
      <InnerException />
      <StackTrace> ... </StackTrace>
    </Error>
    <Error>
      <TimeStamp>2013-11-12T07:27:24.9766747+01:00</TimeStamp>
      <Machine>XY1</Machine>
      <Message> ... </Message>
      <InnerException />
      <StackTrace> ... </StackTrace>
    </Error>
  </Errors>
</Machine>
```

And I have this stylesheet. I'm not very familiar with xslt and all my research on sites like [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) could not help me.

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <body>
        <h2>Status File</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Machine">
    <h5>Machine Information:</h5>
    <div>
      <a href="{@HtmlUri}" target="_blank">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@HtmlUri" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Errors">
    <h5>Errors:</h5>
    <div>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#dd0000">
          <th>Machine</th>
          <th>TimeStamp</th>
          <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Error">
          <tr bgcolor="ff0000">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="./Machine"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="./TimeStamp"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="./Message"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have the machine element at two levels in your data, once inside the error element, once as a root element. Since the matching condition of this template is more specific than of your main template (matching `/`), it is also called for your root element and all the other templates do not get called. Try changing the matching condition from `Machine` to `Error/Machine`

Comment: I think I was not clear enough in my problem description. I want to match my root element (`<Machine HtmlUri="... />`) and not the Machine elements inside `<Error />`. AND I want to display a Table if all Errors.

Comment: I understand that, but you probably want to match the root Machine tag with your first template, since this should match the root `match="/"`. However it will be matched by `match="Machine"`. The later template does not have a `<xsl:apply-templates />` in there which would call all other templates to render the rest of your page.

Comment: Oh yes! your right. I didn't saw the forest behind the trees. I just added the `<xsl:apply-templates />` statement to my `Machine`-template  and it does the job. I choose this solution, because this template has to match some more XML-files, so it has to be more generic (that's why I can't simply extend my main-template).

Comment: Great it works. Just be careful when using the templates like this. A mix of apply-templates and complex templates which select sub-elements tend to not be very stable if the XML gets more complex or you are adding more templates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some usefull comments I solved my problem.

Hence I needed a quite generic XSLT-template I decided to apply the other templates in my `Machine`-template.

That's my working **XSLT** now:

```
  [...]
  <xsl:template match="Machine">
    <h5>Machine Information:</h5>
    <div>
      <a href="{@HtmlUri}" target="_blank">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@HtmlUri" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  [...]
```